# Add from URL disabled for adding custom outlook add-ins

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

Does anyone knows how to enable the "Add from Url" option when adding a custom outlook add-in ? It was working last week but as of now it was disabled.

[image]

I can use the "Add from file" but how come the "Add from url" option has been disabled

Please let me know if there's any tweak needed in azure

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind marking the provided answer as "accepted"? I believe @Twinkle have answered your question and provided resource. This will help other ppl who have the same question.

Comment: Yeah all good. Sorry for that @SlavaIvanov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot enable the option as microsoft has stopped supporting it, they have mentioned a workaround to open the url in browser and download the add-in and then use the Add from File option..article here -> [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-on-the-web-8f2ce816-5df4-44a5-958c-f7f9d6dabdce#:~:text=In%20the%20Custom%20Addins%20section,File%20option%20to%20install%20it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-on-the-web-8f2ce816-5df4-44a5-958c-f7f9d6dabdce#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Custom%20Addins%20section,File%20option%20to%20install%20it)